# Retrieve the latest status of a value by date and time

Tags: excel, datetime

In my excel sheet "Progress Status" I have 2 columns, the first one contain the list of all the test cases that are including during my cycle and in the second column I want to get the latest status of the test case from an other sheet named  "All run TestCases".

I tried using some excel function to get the latest date and time so that I can get the latest status of a test case but I didn't succeed because I don't have a deep knowledge of them, Can someone please help me with this.[The picture shows how my two sheet look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpLn6.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include what you have tried so far. [Here's some help formatting any code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), though surrounding it with back-ticks should do fine in this case. I suspect some combination of INDEX(MATCH()) and adding another column will simplify your problem, or perhaps using a heavy array formula will do what you want.

Comment: HI
I used this code in the column "Last Status" in Sheet "Progress Status"
=IF(MAX(IF( Progress Status!F3=All run TestCases!$A$2:$A$10;$B$2:$B$10));All run TestCases!$D$3:$D$10;"")

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you just combine date and time at one column.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's no possible. When I generate the list of all run test cases, I get the date and time in their own column. I tried to chang ethe sql query to concatenate both of them but it didn't work :(

Comment: You can just sum them. `=B3+C3`. It worked on me.

Comment: If it works, I have a solution with that time.

Comment: I sum both the columns but my code doesn't work exactly how I hoped, Can someone help me with that ???

Comment: Hi @alism
do you have a solution for my question ???

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is the answer. Be sure executionDate and executionTime columns are in the Date and Time format respectively. Create a new column as `FinalTime` with the following function `=B3+C3`. Apply this for the rest. 
Then you can use the following macro. You may need to check `Tools > preferences` in the VBA screen if `OLEDB connection` is clicked.
 I assumed your sheets' names as `TestCases` and `ProgressStatus`. And header of `Test case name` is changed as `Test`. You can either change them on your sheet or in macro.

```
Sub makro()

Dim deneme As String
Dim queryStr As String
Dim con As Object, rs As Object, sorgu$, a$
    Set con = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
    con.Open "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" & _
    ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";extended properties=""Excel 12.0;hdr=yes"""

queryStr = "Select u.[Test]" & _
      ",u.[Status] " & _
    "From [TestCases$] As u " & _
    "Inner Join ( " & _
    "Select [Test] " & _
          ",max(FinalTime)  as [LastDate] " & _
        "From [TestCases$] " & _
        "Group By [Test]) As [q] " & _
"On u.Test = q.Test " & _
" And u.FinalTime = q.LastDate"

    Set rs = con.Execute(queryStr)
    Sheets("ProgressStatus").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is the TestCases and ProgressStatus-with results- sheets I worked on.
[image: TestCases][image: ProgressStatus]

Comment: Hi 
I will rather try to found a solution by using excelfunktion, but thanks any way